How to clone a single Branch using setBranchesToClone() from remote repository to local
I am trying to clone a single branch into my local using jgit library , but I am confused whether to use "refs/heads/" or "refs/remotes/origin".
repo = Git.cloneRepository().setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/remotes/origin/"+ branch)).setBranch(branch).setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userName, pwd)).setURI(uri).setDirectory(new File(toDir)).setDepth(1).call();
If I use the above one I am getting error nothing to fetch.
repo = Git.cloneRepository().setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/"+ branch)).setBranch(branch).setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userName, pwd)).setURI(uri).setDirectory(new File(toDir)).setDepth(1).call();
this is working .
Please shed some light here . Thanks

I believe refs/heads/ should work fine, see example below:

// Clone a single branch into your local repository
Git repo = Git.cloneRepository()
    .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/" + branch)) // Use "refs/heads/" to reference local branches
    .setBranch(branch)
    .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userName, pwd))
    .setURI(uri)
    .setDirectory(new File(toDir))
    .setDepth(1)
    .call();

Hope this helps :)

Exactly it works but I am interested in knowing how it works . Why do I need a reference to a local branch when cloning a branch from remote instead of using the remote branch referenece .

Adding "refs/heads/" before the branch name when cloning from a remote repository indicates that the cloned branch should be treated as a local branch in your repository, enabling you to work with it as if it were created locally.

Hope that helped :)

Thanks Michael, that's the best explanation I got about it , could you please explain the use of refs/remotes/origin.

I have a follow up question as well, while doing a fetch using Fetchcommannd from the remote, in the setRefspecs("refs/heads/branch" + ":"+ " refs/remotes/origin"). Why here as well we specify refs/heads as source and refs/remotes/origin as destination

So in Git, refs/remotes/origin tracks branches from the remote repository named origin. Refs is the top-level directory for references to commits. Remotes contains references to remote repositories. Origin is the default name for the main remote repository when you clone a repo. This system allows Git manage and update remote branch states locally without affecting your working directory.

@ShivanshKaldaik don’t understand your follow up question and also you could accept the original answer if you found it useful, just click the check mark beside it :)
